# Работа с классом из внутри

Tags: c#, классы, конструктор

У меня есть класс скажем `A` (основной класс) и в нем список объектов класса `B`. Сразу после создания класса `B`(его экземпляра) мне нужно добавить его в список из класса `A`.Как предохранитель решил сделать добавку в список в самом классе (самого себя, да). Подумал про конструктор в классе `B` но получается он сам себя вызывать будет рекурсивно. Мне это не подходит. Если это возможно, как можно реализовать? Вот код выше описанный:

```
class A {
     public static List<B> bs = new List<B>();
     bs.Add(new B("Name");//Вот как вот это сделать автоматически в классе B при его инициализации?
}
public class B {
    string name;
    public B (string _name){
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Вот код который будет вызываться рекурсивно:

```
class A {
public static List<B> bs = new List<B>();
}
public class B{
    string name;
    public B (string name){
       this.name = name;
       A.bs.Add(new B(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите сделать что-то непонятное. Конструктор не может вызываться рекурсивно, он вызывается при вызове оператора `new`.

Comment: @LLENN честно сам в шоке как до такого додумался но все же. Конструкторы для чего придумали? Что бы не забыть инициализировать переменные внутри класса. почему бы не найти решение для такой проблемы?

Comment: @LLENN хотел просто добавить в список экземпляр этого же класса.

Comment: Тогда не понятно зачем вы создавали новый объект а не добавляли ссылку на текущий в этот список.

Comment: Я понимаю, что вам дали ответ и он работает, но... Осмыслите задачу в терминах "репозитория": есть сущность Entity, есть место хранения ("база" в памяти - список), вы хотите чтобы сразу при создании сущности (обязанность, которую выносят в Фабрику) её сразу сохраняло в базу, что считается нарушением SRP.

Comment: @AK а чем это чревато, позвольте спросить?

Comment: Черевато неподдерживаемой кашей в коде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понятная задача до конца, но, возможно, вы имеете в виду это:

```
class A
{
    public static List<B> Bs { get; } = new List<B>();
}

class B
{
    public B()
    {
        A.Bs.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробую... Секунду

Comment: Отлично работает . Спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)